# Removing empty elements from an array/list in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I've a big array under the name `all_data_array`:

```
all_data_array = [[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[0, 1, 2, 3], ['foo', 'moo', 'bar', 'sis'], ['05-03-2014', '10-03-2014', '14-03-2014', '20-03-2014'], ['05-03-2014', '10-03-2014', '14-03-2014', '20-03-2014'], ['12:00', '12:03', '12:01', '12:01'], ['12:05', '12:08', '12:06', '12:06'], [123, 322, 345, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0.1149597018957138, 0.920006513595581, 1.0062587261199951, 1.0062587261199951]]]
```

In this example, inside `all_data_array` I have two arrays:
1. The 'empty' one: `[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]`
2. The filled one (which is very long), `[[0, 1, 2, 3], ['foo', 'moo', 'bar', 'sis'], ['05-03-2014', '10-03-2014', '14-03-2014', '20-03-2014'], ['05-03-2014', '10-03-2014', '14-03-2014', '20-03-2014'], ['12:00', '12:03', '12:01', '12:01'], ['12:05', '12:08', '12:06', '12:06'], [123, 322, 345, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0.1149597018957138, 0.920006513595581, 1.0062587261199951, 1.0062587261199951]]`

How can I remove from `all_data_array` all the empty arrays? The solution for the example is just `all_data_array.pop[0]` but I would like to have a general solution if it's possible

I tried something like this but it's not working and I'm a bit lost:

```
for i in all_data_array:
    for m in xrange(len(all_data_array)):
        if m == []:
            print "EMPTY"
        else:
            print "WITH CONTENT"
```

Thanks in advace

Comment: replace `if m == []:` with `if not m:`

Comment: What if one of the subelements is empty?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove all empty nested lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368053/remove-all-empty-nested-lists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `all`:

```
not_empty_ones = []

for el in all_data_array:
    if all(el):
        not_empty_ones.append(el)
print not_empty_ones
```

Since this is an list consisting of lists themselves, you need to check if each element inside are empty or not. This can be achived with [all built-in](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all).

Comment: I recommend using list comprehension for that: `[el for el in all_data_array if all(el)]`. because an excessive use of `append` takes a lot of memory.

Comment: +1 for tayfun for the use of 'all' and +1 for slallum for using list comprehension and pointing the issue about append

Comment: `all` will also exclude non empty lists with values evaluating to false. e.g. `[[0],[0]]` will be excluded. If you want to keep such elements then I'd suggest use `len(list(chain.from_iterable(array)))`. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

did you try this?

```
all_data_array_no_empty = [x for x in all_data_array if all(x)]
```

Comment: Why? list1 = [[],[1,2,3],[],[],['a','b']] list2 = [x for x in list1 if x != []] got [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b']]

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary exactly .

Comment: @amit Have a look at OP's input first.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, you we're right, didn't notice the list of empty lists in its input. 10x.

Answer (score 0):

this will do it despite the length of the empty array/list:

```
from itertools import chain
[array for array in all_data_array if len(list(chain.from_iterable(array))) > 0]
```

if your lists are non empty you get different results if you use `all` instead of `len(list(chain.from_iterable(array))) > 0`:

```
>>> all_data_array = [[[0], []], [[1, 1, 1]]]
>>> [l for l in all_data_array if len(list(chain.from_iterable(l))) > 0]
[[[0], []], [[1, 1, 1]]]      # <-- element [[0], []] will be included
>>> [el for el in all_data_array if all(el)]
[[[1, 1, 1]]]                 # <-- element [[0], []] will be excluded
```